# Respect default action in keymap with Meta keys?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I have a keymap which uses `[t]` to bind a default command which should be executed if any key not bound in the map is pressed. This is described in the documentation of `define-key` and it works for the most part. **BUT** if I bind a Meta combination in that map, any other Meta key combination will skip this default command from there on.

Example Code to illustrate the problem:

```
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key map (kbd "M-a") 'some-command)
  (define-key map [t] (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (message "this will be skipped by Meta combinations")))
  (set-transient-map map))
```

I want to be able to bind a command to a Meta combination, but let other Meta combinations still run the default.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For historical reasons, `M-key` and `ESC key` are mostly treated as equivalent. Physical terminals, and terminal emulators, communicate with the application by sending characters, and there's no character for “meta *character*” (whereas [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) includes control characters corresponding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> and a few punctuation characters). Two conventions exist to encode <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>character</kbd>: set the 8th bit on <kbd>character</kbd> (which is only applicable with a 7-bit character set), or send the `ESC` character followed by the character from the keychord.

Graphical terminals send keychords to the application, so they can encode <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>character</kbd> and more generally <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> just fine. However, to preserve compatibility with text terminals, Emacs internally translates <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> to `ESC` <kbd>key</kbd> (or more generally [`meta-prefix-char`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Functions-for-Key-Lookup.html#index-meta_002dprefix_002dchar) <kbd>key</kbd> but I suspect that changing `meta-prefix-char` would break a lot of modes).

Thus, if you're defining a fallback binding in a keymap, include that binding for `ESC` as well.

```
(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key map [?\e t] (lambda ()
             (interactive)
             (message "this will be triggered by Meta combinations")))
  (define-key map (kbd "M-a") 'some-command)
  (define-key map [t] (lambda ()
                        (interactive)
                        (message "this will be skipped by Meta combinations")))
  (set-transient-map map))
```